# create each row as a file and each column as the content?

Tags: vba, excel

[1]: 
How can I created each row a a file and each file containing the headers and the value of each column. Thanks.

Example:

```
      Name Age   Sex
Fi1e1  Maria 24    F
File2  Agnes 23    F
File3   John  23   M
```

Result:
All files Contains the name of each column and the values:

```
File1
Name Age Sex
Maria 24  F  

File2
Name Age Sex
Agnes  23  F
```

Thanks.

---

Here's what I got so far but I can't get the other columns to be inside the file.

```
Sub Export_Files()
Dim fiLEs, sFN
Dim rArticleName As Range
Dim rContent As Range
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim oFS As Object
Dim oTxt As Object

'fiLEsr = path to the folder you want to export to
'oSh = The sheet where your data is stored
fiLEs = "C:\Documents\Users\"
Set oSh = Sheet1

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    Set rContent = rArticleName.Offset(, 1)


    sFN = rArticleName.Value & ".csv"
    Set oTxt = oFS.OpenTextFile(fiLEs & "\" & sFN, 2, True)
    oTxt.Write rContent.Value
    oTxt.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Question is too vague - eg what kind of file?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post the code you've tried and what's not working with it. [How to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Tim Williams. Ok, I just want to create a csv. files which will be name on the value of the first column and the content of the csv file will be the row but I also want to have the header type( Name, Age, Sex) on each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Export_Files()
Dim fiLEs, sFN
Dim rArticleName As Range
Dim rContent As Range, rHdr As Range
Dim sHdr  As String, sContent As String
Dim oSh As Worksheet
Dim a As Object, v
Set a = Application

    fiLEs = "D:\temp\" '"C:\Documents\Users\"
    Set oSh = Sheet1

    Set rHdr = oSh.Range(oSh.Range("B1"), _
               oSh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    sHdr = Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rHdr.Value)), ",")

    For Each rArticleName In oSh.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
        v = rArticleName.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            Set rContent = rArticleName.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, _
                                             rHdr.Columns.Count)
            sContent = Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rContent.Value)), ",")
            sFN = v & ".csv"
            CreateTextFile fiLEs & sFN, sHdr & vbCrLf & sContent
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub CreateTextFile(sPath As String, sContent As String)
    Static fso As Object
    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    With fso.CreateTextFile(sPath)
        .write sContent
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim. I am getting error on the part With fso.CreateTextFile(Spath) under the sub createtextfile.

Comment: What error?  Need to be more specific.

Comment: Its run time error '76':  Path not found and when I debug it it shows on the With fso.CreateTextFile(Spath). I really appreacite the help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a folder D:\temp\ ?  You will need to adjust the code if not.